# Power BI function that checks if multiple specified values (numbers) exist in a column

Tags: list, function, powerbi, contains, exists

Is there a function in Power BI that can check whether a list of specified values (numbers) exists in a column?

For example, in the image below, I have a column with some values and another one with 0 and 1s. You can see that some values are marked with 1 and some with 0. In order to do this, I used IF function, but this is just too cumbersome.

I am looking for a formula that can check if the values from a list like {XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, etc}  exist in a column and that can easily be edited when I need to add other values.

Thank you and have a good day!
Best,
Denis

[image]

Comment: You didn't said how you want to do that, not even are you using DAX or M. Take a look at [List.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-contains) function for example. You can use it like this `= Table.SelectRows(Table1, each List.Contains({'5006', '4905', '4876'}, [Column1]))`

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is in Dax or M. both are fine. 
I have tried the formula above and unfortunately I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding a custom column for example. If we assume your table is named `Table` and first column is named `Value`, then add a custom column like this:

[image]

Where the list contains all the values of interest. This will give you a boolean column `Flag`:

[image]

If you want an integer column with `0` and `1` values, then change the column to something like this:

```
= if (List.Contains({"5006", "4905"}, [Value])) then 1 else 0
```

[image]